# How to change color in angular based on value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How do we change the color dynamically based on a value in angular typescript template?

For example if `item.status == 'Active' && ang item.role == 'Admin'` set color to `color:#00B0D` else set color to `#707070`.

```
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" style="color:#00B0DB">
  check_circle
</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directive to apply conditional inline styles.

Example:

```html
<mat-icon
  aria-hidden="false"
  aria-label="Example home icon"
  [ngStyle]="{'color': item.status === 'Active' && item.role === 'Admin' ? '#00B0DB' : '#707070'}"
>check_circle</mat-icon>
```

Similarly, you can use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive to apply CSS classes conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ngStyle` you can set specific styles based on some condition.

Example:

```html
<mat-icon
  [ngStyle]="{'color': item.status === 'Active' && item.role === 'Admin' ? '#00B0DB' : '#707070'}"
>check_circle</mat-icon>
```